# Bayesian Netwotk structure learning

Tags: bnlearn

Using the bnlearn package I can learn the structure of a BN just by passing my dataset as parameter, for example:

bn1 <- blnearn :: hc (dataset)

Or must I pass some edges as prior knowledge eg:

wl = data.frame (from = c ("A", "B"), to = c ("B", "C")) 
bn1 <- blnearn :: hc (datase, whitelist = wl)

What I mean is the bnlearn algorithms has capacity to learn the structure from data only or always need some help with prior knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

bnlearn features both structural learning and manual creation of structures in your network.

Basic structural learning is as easy as you assumed:

```
bn1 <- hc(x = dataset)
```

If you have prior knowledge about the structure that you want to include, you can use the whitelist or blacklist argument. But this is optional.

For starters I suggest this [Introductory tutorial on Bayesian networks in R by
Jacinto Arias](https://jacintoarias.github.io/bayesnetRtutorial/) including an [example on structural learning](https://jacintoarias.github.io/bayesnetRtutorial/#structural_learning).